# Express subrouter returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this router (http/api/ping.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
    res.send("You called /api/ping");
});

module.exports = router;
```

This router is embedded into this router (http/api/index.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('You called /api');
});

router.use('/ping', require('./ping'));

module.exports = router;
```

And this router is used by my Express.js app (app.js):

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('./config').logger;

// Create app
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// App config
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', require('./http/api'));

// Display requests on console
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    logger.trace(req.method, req._parsedUrl.href);
    next()
});

module.exports = {
    app: app,
    server: server
};
```

When I run the app, `/api` returns `You called /api`, but `/api/ping` gives me a 404.

I am using Node 6.9.1 and Express ^4.14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think order matters in this scenario. Try putting `/ping` above the `/` get route.

```
router.use('/ping', require('./ping'));
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('You called /api');
});
```

Also in your ping route you say the path to your route is `/ping` you also say it is `/ping` when you import it to the other router, which would make the path `/api/ping/ping`

change

```
router.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
    res.send("You called /api/ping");
});
```

to

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("You called /api/ping");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck :(

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a ton! I'll accept the answer in five minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think your routing is incorrect on this line

```
router.use('/ping', require('./ping'));
```

this will point to http/api/ping/ping

it should be

```
router.use('/', require('./ping'));
```

Comment: Think this might be right. In the problem, /api/ping/ping would return the response